# "Permission Denied" Firebase Error due to Security Rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I am getting `Permission denied` error after calling `setValue()` on `firebaseRef`

My Rule Looks Like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read" : "auth.provider == 'google'",
      ".write" : "auth.provider == 'google'",
      "hashTags": {
        "$userEncodedEmail": {
          "$hashTag": {
            ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['createByUserEmail', 'name','timeStampLastUsed','tasksKeys'])",                
            "createByUserEmail": {
              ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z0-9,_%+-]+@[A-Z0-9,-]+,[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)" 
            },
            "name": {
              ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length <= 500"
            },
            "timeStampLastUsed": {
              ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['timestamp'])",
              "timestamp": {
                ".validate": "newData.isNumber()"
              },
              "$other": {
                ".validate": "false"
              }
            },
            "tasksKeys": {
            },
            "$other": {
                ".validate": "false"
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

And the Java Model is:

```
public class HashTagModel {

    private HashMap<String, Object> timeStampLastUsed;
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @Expose
    private String createByUserEmail;
    private List<String> tasksKeys;
    ...
}
```

I have also tried:

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read" : "auth.provider == 'google'",
      ".write" : "auth.provider == 'google'",
      "hashTags": {
        "$userEncodedEmail": {
          "$hashTag": {
            ...
            "tasksKeys": {
               "$taskId": {
                   ".validate": "newData.isString()"
               }
            },
            ...
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Your security rule checks for the presence of a key called `taskKeys`. The Java class has a field called `tasksKeys`. The latter has an extra `s` in there.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen i have updated but still same problem.

Comment: It's impossible to say much more without seeing the data that you send. You can see what is sent to the Firebase server by calling `Firebase.getDefaultContext().setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG)`. Usual troubleshooting is to take that and try it in the Simulator tab of your dashboard. You should get the same problem, but with details about which security rule is failing.

Comment: From Simulator i found that the regex is not working correctly even for correct email.

Comment: Also i think `Firebase.getDefaultContext()` does not exists, there is `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogger()` but not sure what should i pass in the argument.

Comment: Darn, it's indeed `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Level.DEBUG)`. That'll teach me to type Android code instead of copy/pasting it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen :)